# Can't access the option value using javascript on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, select

I have the following setup

```
"<form name=\"mylimit\" style=\"float:left\">
                <select name=\"limiter\" onChange=\"limit()\">
                <option selected=\"selected\">&nbsp;</option>"; ...
```

I wrote a js script to access the selected value of the selectField 'limiter' like so:

```
 var w = document.mylimit.limiter.selectedIndex;
```

var url_add = document.mylimit.limiter.**options[w].value**;

//On every browser i get the expected value except on Internet Explorer. think IExplorer dont like the bolded portion above. Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried document.getElementById() instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE is looking for the value attribute. It looks like other browsers are defaulting to the text displayed as the value if value="" is not found on the option tag. The following is what works on all major browsers.

```
<form name="mylimit" style="float:left">
    <select name="limiter" onChange="limit()">
        <option selected="selected" value='foo'>bar</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    var index = document.mylimit.limiter.selectedIndex;
    var value = document.mylimit.limiter.options[index].value;
    alert(value); // Alerts 'foo'
</script>
```

This way you can have a seperate value and display for each option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out one of these

document.mylimit.limiter.options[document.mylimit.limiter.selectedIndex].value

or

document.getElementById('limiter').options[document.getElementById('limiter').selectedIndex].value

This should help I think

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("limiter").value` works as well.

Comment: the answer is not complete...Gordon below worked out pretty well. thanks for your help